# Flutter: how to use if conditional inside InputDecoration's errorText property?

Tags: flutter

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
              ),
              hintText: 'What do people call you?',
              labelText: 'User ID',
              errorText: <------ I want to use conditional here            
            ),
```

I want to render different errorText according to different conditions. I'd tried to use `Text()` widget to do this but then it did not work. How can I use different text inside `errorText` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `ternary operator` `(condition)? then:else`

In your code:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
              ),
              hintText: 'What do people call you?',
              labelText: 'User ID',
              errorText: (true)? "Error true":"Error false"
            ),
```

for multiple conditions :

```
errorText: (x == 1)? "Error 1": (x == 2)?"Error 2":"Error else"
```

Or you can create a function that return a string depending on conditions

```
errorText: _getError()
---
String _getError(){
   if(x == 1) return "Error 1";
...
}
```

Comment: I want to have more like 2 conditions. It is for user ID and want to display what they are missing.

Comment: You can put a validator on that input field, and the validator can return arbitrary strings that will be inserted into error text.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to use the `errorStyle` together with the `errorText` parameters.  Looks like that accepts any `TextStyle` so you can have it as you want it.